# Stripe JS Invalidate/Destroy Token?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to invalidate/destroy a token generated by Stripe so that it can not be used anymore. Per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) `Stripe.card.createToken` creates a token upon success in the callback `stripeResponseHandler(status, response)`. The token id can be accessed via `response.id`.

The token is then valid until the user makes a payment.

However, I want to be able to invalidate that token and prevent it from being used again. Is there any form of `Stripe.card.destroyToken` method that you can pass in the generated response.id and prevent that token from ever being used?

Comment: You cannot delete a token, why would you not want to use it? If you don't want to use it then just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

No, tokens cannot be destroyed. But as they can only be used with your secret API key, and can only be used once, they don't present much of a risk. If you don't want to use a particular token, then simply discard it and forget about it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!